# Search engine description with throwback theme

Tags: support, bug, design, seo

I searched DuckDuckGo just now and a StackOverflow question came up as a search result. Instead of a meaningful page description or snippet, below the DuckDuckGo search result entry appeared the following:

> Back to the future! Just like the '90s, good things have to come to an
>   end. If you want to switch to the current site, you'll find the option
>   here.

This is not helpful for users, and should not happen again. I expect it will be a short-lived problem, as the throwback theme seems to already be deactivated.

BTW, it was likely an accessibility problem as well as an SEO one.

Comment: It won't happen again ... they never run the same April fools twice ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a caching issue on DuckDuckGo's end, as I don't see this happening in Google or Bing.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog I recall a similar case where the cookie consent or one of those other headers appeared in all Google search results. While I agree this might be related to the particular crawler, there is some merit in reporting it and keeping it as for a one day event it is a bit weird to sacrifice search content. The "Google" issue was also resolved by SE, not Google.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog: The fact that it still shows up after the theme has been deactivated is a result of caching, but the fact that it was ever shown to the search engine at all is SE's fault.

Comment: The problem was solved by the nature of it being a one-day (or two) event. The re-creation of the problem for some other system-wide change remains a possibility, as this is a repeat, in spirit, of the cookie consent issue. It may not be a "bug" in the code, but it does seem to be a "bug" in the coding. Those who cannot learn from the past are doomed to repeat it. Let's use this as a reminder to learn from the past.